# How to access module's privatedata from a binary PowerShell Cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell

In my module's psd1 file I define the following:

```
PrivateData = @{
    verbose = $true
}
```

I can access PrivateData from a regular (non-binary) Cmdlet like so:

```
if ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData['verbose'])
```

However, I can't seem to follow the same pattern from my C# (binary) module. Here is what I tried:

```
 var privateData = (Dictionary<string, object>)MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData;
 WriteVerbose((string)privateData["verbose"]);
```

This throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to access `privateData`.